# undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdminOrdersController:Class

Tags: rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, testcase

**spec_helper.rb**

```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
    end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'support/controller_macros'

# include shared examples
require 'support/shared_examples'

require 'devise'

# Testing inline
require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
# Loading Devise Warden into the controller tests.
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  # include fabricators
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fabricators"
end
```

**spec/controllers/admin/orders_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative '../../support/controller_macros'

describe Admin::OrdersController, :type => :controller do 
    describe 'GET index' do
        @admin = Fabricate(:admin)
        setup_admin(@admin)
        context 'Admin not logged in' do
         it_behaves_like 'requires sign in' do
          get :index 
         end
        end
     end
end
```

**spec/support/controller_macros.rb**

```
def setup_admin(a_user = nil)
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
    sign_in a_user || Fabricate(:admin)
  end
```

This is the full error stack that I'm getting

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/admin/orders_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  describe Admin::OrdersController, :type => :controller do 
    describe 'GET index' do
        @admin = Fabricate(:admin)
        setup_admin(@admin)
        context 'Admin not logged in' do
          it_behaves_like 'requires sign in' do
            get :index 
          end
        end

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdminOrdersController:Class
# /home/riya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:30:in `block in <module:ControllerHelpers>'
# ./spec/controllers/admin/orders_controller_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00007 seconds (files took 1.85 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

I tried every possible solution, but nothing worked for me.

I am using rails-5.2, rspec-3.9,

Even when I run 'rspec' only, I get this error for all the specs.

Comment: Please update with the test file that fails.

Comment: @razvans please check now.

Comment: add `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of `admin/orders_controller_spec.rb`. See if it works.

Comment: @razvans It's already there.

Comment: Then `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller` instead of Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers ?

Comment: @razvans Tried that also, but didn't work.

Comment: Please add the entire error trace.

Comment: @razvans Added.

Comment: @Riya `config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller` defined in `spec_helper.rb` as well as in `rails_helper.rb` could you please try removing it from `spec_helper.rb`?